# Wordpress "Press This" plugin modification

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to change this:

```
if ( $selection )
            $content .= __('via ');

        $content .= sprintf( "<a href='%s'>%s</a>.</p>", esc_url( $url ), esc_html( $title ) );
    }
```

I want to show only "via domain.tld" with hyperlink to full adress instead of "via The Full Name Of Entry"

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself? I'm sorry to disappoint, but Stack Overflow is a community of people here to help you with specific programming problems, not a community of people who are here to work for you for free.

Comment: Yes, I tried to solve this problem by myself, but nothing. Man I am runing some kind of web servers, and do some php coding, do you think I am joking? Just really I can't find a solution, how to get basic domain.tld only ... I tried everything I could think of.